# Downloading iOS 8.4 .dmg file or later

Tags: ios, dmg

I'm trying to download or to get .dmg of iOS 8.4 or later and all I can get from Apple dev center is ipws file. Is there any way to convert/extract/whatever this .ipws to a valid dmg image (that can be eventually mounted ?) or is there any link from where I can get a valid .dmg image of ios8.4 or later? 
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to decrypt it first, here is a complete guide to mounting and editing ipsw files.

[Decrypting and mounting IPSW files](http://iphonehowto3easy.blogspot.co.uk/2010/04/how-to-decrypt-mount-and-edit-root.html?m=1)

Hope this helps,

Tiferrei